# SQL TO LINQ- Conversion

Tags: linq-to-entities

How do I convert this into Linq?

```
    SELECT 
        ps.forename,Count(ps.Forename) 

FROM 
        [Dbase].[dbo].[Absence] ab
INNER JOIN
        [Dbase].[dbo].[Person] ps
On 
ab.empid=ps.id
where ps.forename='hari'
GROUP BY ps.forename
Having Count(ps.forename)>2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here  you go.

```
            var result = (from x in Absence
                     join y in Person on x.empid equals ps.id
                     group x by new { z = ps.forename == "hari" } into g
                     where g.Count() > 2
                     select new
                     {
                         g.Key,
                         cnt = g.Count()
                     });
```