# Linq to Entities Lambda expression COUNT

Tags: linq-to-entities, count, lambda

> The following query expression currently returns the list of CUISINES
>   in the CUISINE table.  I would also like to return the COUNT of each
>   number of restaurants offering that cuisine from the RESTAURANT table
>   using the CUISINE_ID field in the RESTAURANT table.  I tried using the 'let'
>   but received an error stating that "**can't convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type**."  Your help would be appreciated. ~susan~

```
public IEnumerable <string> getCuisines()
{
    var cuisineList = from CUISINE in db.CUISINEs.Include("RESTAURANT")
                     orderby CUISINE.CUISINE_NAME ascending
                     select CUISINE.CUISINE_NAME;
    return cuisineList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
var cuisineList = from x in db.CUISINEs
                  join y in db.RESTAURANT on x.CUISINE_ID equals y.CUISINE_ID 
                  group x by x.CUISINE_ID into g                            
                  select new 
                  {  
                     key = g.Key,
                     Count = g.Count(),
                     g
                  }
```

You can also refer [SQL TO LINQ- Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469967/sql-to-linq-conversion/6479248#6479248)